# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'TemplateBodyResponse'. 'Select' not found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-webapi

i have bellow response model

```
public  class GetSearchNotificationTemplateResponse
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public TemplateBodyResponse templateBody { get; set; }
    }
    public class TemplateBodyResponse
    {
        public string EmailContent { get; set; }
        public string SMSContent { get; set; }
        public string PushNotificationsContent { get; set; }
    }
    public class SearchNotificationTemplateResponse
    {
        public List<GetSearchNotificationTemplateResponse>  TemplateResponses { get; set; }
    }
```

templatebody response contain json format  like bellow

```
{\"EmailContent\":SampleData\",\"SMSContent\":SampleData\",\"PushNotificayionsContent\":SampleData|"}
```

my bs like bellow

```
  public async Task<SearchNotificationTemplateResponse> SearchNotificationTemplate1(Contracts.Models.SearchNotificationRequest request)
        {
            SearchNotificationTemplateResponse Response = new SearchNotificationTemplateResponse()
            {
                TemplateResponses = new List<Contracts.Models.GetSearchNotificationTemplateResponse>()
            };
            Response.TemplateResponses = (from res in await notificationRepository.SearchNotificationTemplate(request)
                                          select new Contracts.Models.GetSearchNotificationTemplateResponse()
                                          {
                                              Id = res.NotificationTemplateId,
                                              Name = res.TemplateName,
                                              IsActive = res.IsActive,
                                              templateBody = (from list in  notificationRepository.GetTemplateBodyById(res.NotificationTemplateId)
                                                              select new Contracts.Models.TemplateBodyResponse()
                                                              {
                                                                  EmailContent = list.EmailContent,
                                                                  SMSContent = list.SMSContent,
                                                                  PushNotificationsContent = list.PushNotificationsContent
                                                              }).ToList()
                                          }).ToList();
            return Response;
        }
```

my repository logic is

```
  public async Task<TemplateBodyResponse> GetTemplateBodyById(int id)
            {
                var res = this.DbSet.Where(a => a.NotificationTemplateId == id).FirstOrDefault();
                TemplateBodyResponse deserializedTemplate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TemplateBodyResponse>(res.Body);
                return await Task.FromResult(deserializedTemplate);
            }
```

**res.Body** having above json data.
 i want assign those deserializedtemplate  response to templatebody object.im unable to get it

Comment: First, you should NOT call the ".Result" property on your GetTemplateBodyById. Make an await call on it and store the result into a variable.
Then, to answer your question, this method returns a TemplateBodyResponse, which is not an IEnumerable, but you're trying to make a linq request on it. It's just not supposed to work. Link is for manipulating lists and arrays, and you're not doing that

Comment: Miiite ..i tried not able to getting

Comment: Please, do not post a code as images

Comment: Pavel Anikhouski ..ok

Comment: And why is your method GetTemplateBodyById async ? You're not executing any async code in it. But anyways, your code should just be templateBody = notificationRepository.GetTemplateBodyById(res.NotificationTemplateId)

Comment: miiite im getting error like "Invalid property identifier character: \\. Path '', line 1, position 1."